# For any positive integer n, prove $ \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)} + \frac{3n+1}{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can see
$$ \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)} + \frac{3n+1}{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}
\\ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n}+ \frac{1}{2n+1} \right]
$$

The biggest term in  $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2}$ is $ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, which is $< \frac{1}{2n}$ for all $n > 0$. Unable to proceed after this.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\mapsto \frac 1 {x^2}$ is non-increasing on positive integers, we can bound using integrals:
$$
 \int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t^2} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac 1 {k^2} \leq \int_{n}^{2n}\frac{dt}{t^2}
$$
The left-hand side is $$\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac {1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac n{(n+1)(2n+1)}$$
The right-hand side is
$$\begin{split}
\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{dt}{t^2}&=\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}-\int_{2n}^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}\\
&=\frac n{(n+1)(2n+1)}+\frac 1 {n(n+1)}-\frac 1 {2n(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac n{(n+1)(2n+1)}+\frac {3n+1}{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}
\end{split}
$$
I can't get the factor 4 in the denominator.

Comment: If you take $$\int_{n + 1/2}^{2n+1/2} \frac{dt}{t^2} = \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{2n+\frac{1}{2}}$$ for the right hand side, I'd expect you can get the $4$.